# Select top 3 viewed images of every user from a table

Tags: mysql, sql, select, group-by, limit

I know this type of question has been asked multiple times but I am not able to find a good answer of my question. 
I tried to fetch top 3 viewed records of every person from the table.

## mytable

```
id    user_id     views
1       5          6
2       5          3
3       6          5  
4       7          4  
5       9          14  
6       5          3
7       5          8
8       6          7
9       7         15
10      9         13
11      9         13  
12      9         18
13      6          8
14      8          0
```

## result

```
id      user_id    views
12       9          18
9        7          15
5        9          14
10       9          13
13       6          8
7        5          8
8        6          7
1        5          6
3        6          5
4        7          4
2        5          3
14       8          0
```

I followed this link http://www.xaprb.com/blog/2006/12/07/how-to-select-the-firstleastmax-row-per-group-in-sql/

## My Query

```
select *
from mytable
where (
   select count(*) from mytable as f
   where f.user_id = mytable.user_id and f.views >= mytable.views
) < 4 order by user_id desc;
```

But this query is not fetching those records where views are equal.
Please point me to the right direction.

Comment: i am not clear with your question. but, you can simply get the result (you mention in your post) by this query ... `SELECT * FROM mytable ORDER BY views DESC`

Comment: @TunZarniKyaw Almost. [10, 9, 13] and [11, 9, 13 ] are not both in the result-set.

Comment: @TunZarniKyaw, I am trying to fetch only 3 most viewed records of every user from the table. Above is just sample data and there are multiple entry of user. I just need 3 most viewed records of every user.

Comment: @TarynEast, [10, 9, 13] or [11, 9, 13 ] I need any of them not both

Comment: MySQL lacks analytic functions that make this easy, but there are options:  http://www.xaprb.com/blog/2006/12/07/how-to-select-the-firstleastmax-row-per-group-in-sql/

Comment: @GoatCO, I have posted same link in my question.

Comment: @Santosh - yes, this is what I was pointing out to TunZamiKyaw and why his solution wouldn't solve it for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT id, user_id, views 
FROM (SELECT IF(@lastUserId = @lastUserId:=t.user_id, @ID:=@ID+1, @ID:=1) AS userNo, 
                 t.id, t.user_id, t.views
        FROM mytable t, (SELECT @ID:=0, @lastUserId:=0) A 
        ORDER BY t.user_id, t.views DESC
      ) AS A 
WHERE userNo <= 3 
ORDER BY views DESC
```

Check the [**SQL FIDDLE DEMO**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e422cb/1)

**OUTPUT**

```
| ID | USER_ID | VIEWS |
|----|---------|-------|
| 12 |       9 |    18 |
|  9 |       7 |    15 |
|  5 |       9 |    14 |
| 10 |       9 |    13 |
|  7 |       5 |     8 |
| 13 |       6 |     8 |
|  8 |       6 |     7 |
|  1 |       5 |     6 |
|  3 |       6 |     5 |
|  4 |       7 |     4 |
|  2 |       5 |     3 |
| 14 |       8 |     0 |
```

Comment: This query is fetching only one user's records. I need all users with 3 most viewed records. Thanks for your help.